# UnsatisfiedLinkError couldn't find "libnative-lib.so" with libnative-lib.so visible in aar file

Tags: android-ndk, aar

So I built an Android aar library which contains a native library (libnative-lib.so). Due to backward compatibility consideration, it's only built for armeabi and x86 architectures.

Now, I place the aar file and use it in my "client" app, I can clearly see the libnative-lib.so are under the aar's jni/armeabi and jni/x86 folders.

But the app crashes with this message:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ...
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libnative-lib.so"
```

This looks like the client app isn't able to find the nativelib from aar. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually in my case, due to the mentioned backward compatibility consideration, I need to put this in my library's build.gradle:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libnative-lib.so'
    exclude 'lib/x86_64/libnative-lib.so'
}
```

to guard the build away from the unwanted architectures.

Comment: This will cause the UnsatisfiedLinkError couldn't find “libnative-lib.so” error in almost all devices

Comment: @CésarCruz if you put both line, probably. But this solution was good for when I posted the question, back when armeabi and X86 were still supported